# Is the idea in the below sentence comprehensible? Is it grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, british-english

He blustered to the extent that it contorted his abdomen until he heard his stomach growling through hunger.

Comment: It is grammatical. It is not idiomatic. Whether it conveys what you want it to convey is unknown since you don’t say what that is.

Comment: I am writing a novel, and the sentence is a part of it.

Comment: @RiteshJha you had better hope that your readers' knowledge of anatomy is even less than yours, otherwise they will find your description unconvincing.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey abdomen is a common word, in my opinion. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but it would be very odd if 'blustering' could contort it, and why should it then be heard growling? And why not before?

Comment: Blustering means to talk in a threating way, I want you speak something in a "blustering" way, you'll find that it actually contorts your abdomen.

Comment: And the reason "growling" didn't happen before is that "blustering" takes energy from body, and before he wasn't using his body nor mind to such an extent so as to cause "growling". I hope you got what I am saying  or I suck at explaining things